# Remove from the beginning till certain part in a string

Tags: perl, string, bash, sed, awk

I work with strings like

```
abc_dsdsds_ss_gsgsdsfsdf_ewew_wewewewewew_adf
```

and I need to get a new one where I remove in the original string everything from the beginning till the last appearance of "_" and the next characters (can be 3, 4, or whatever number)

so in this case I would get

```
_adf
```

How could I do it with "sed" or another bash tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed 's/^(.*)_([^_]*)$/_\2/' < input.txt
```

Comment: Good solution. However, you do not need the first group at all, and forgot to backslash the parenthesis. I bet you can use non backslashed parenthesis if you pass the `-e` flag to GNU sed, though.

Comment: Fair enough. I pretty much add backslashes at random anyways, when hacking through a sed command.

Answer (score 5):

Regular expression pattern matching is greedy.  Hence ^.*_ will match all characters up to and including the last _.  Then just put the underscore back in:

```
echo abc_dsdsds_ss_gsgsdsfsdf_ewew_wewewewewew_adf | sed 's/^.*_/_/'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just group the last non-underscore characters preceded by the last underscore with `\(_[^_]*\)`, then reference this group with `\1`:

```
 sed 's/^.*\(_[^_]*\)$/\1/'
```

Result:

```
$ echo abc_dsdsds_ss_gsgsdsfsdf_ewew_wewewewewew_adf | sed 's/^.*\(_[^_]*\)$/\1/'
_adf
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to modify the string, or just find everything after the last underscore? The regex to find the last _{anything} would be `/(_[^_]+)$/` ($ matches the end of the string), or if you also want to match a trailing underscore with nothing after it, `/(_[^_]*)$/`.

Unless you really need to modify the string in place instead of just finding this piece, or you really want to do this from the command line instead of a script, this regex is a bit simpler (you tagged this with perl, so I wasn't sure quite how committed to using just the command line as opposed to a simple script you were).

If you do need to modify the string in place, `sed -i 's/(_[^_]+)$/\1/' myfile` or `sed -i 's/(_[^_]+)$/\1/g' myfile`. The `-i` (edit: I decided not to be lazy and look up the proper syntax...) the `-i` flag will just overwrite the old file with the new one. If you want to create a new file and not clobber the old one, `sed -e 's/.../.../g' oldfile > newfile`. The `g` after the `s///` will do this for all instances in the file you pass into sed; leaving it out just replaces the first instance.

If the string is not by itself at the end of the line, but rather embedded in other text. but just separated by whitespace, replace the `$` with `\s`, which will match a whitespace character (the end of a word).

Comment: s/he wants to call this from bash, so there isn't really a distinction.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that after writing my first short answer... and it grew from there. Actually, good call, my wording was a bit off there. Fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In Perl, you could do this:

```
my $string = "abc_dsdsds_ss_gsgsdsfsdf_ewew_wewewewewew_adf";

if ( $string =~ m/(_[^_]+)$/ ) {
    print $1;
}
```

[Edit]
A Perl one liner approach (ie, can be run from bash directly):

```
perl -lne 'm/(_[^_]+)$/ && print $1;' infile > outfile
```

Or using substitution:

```
perl -pe 's/.*(_[^_]+)$/$1/' infile > outfile
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have strings like these in bash variables (I don't see that specified in the question), you can use [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
s="abc_dsdsds_ss_gsgsdsfsdf_ewew_wewewewewew_adf"
t="_${s##*_}"
echo "$t"  # ==> _adf
```

Answer (score 0):

A Perl way:

```
echo 'abc_dsdsds_ss_gsgsdsfsdf_ewew_wewewewewew_adf' | \
perl -e 'print ((split/(_)/,<>)[-2..-1])'
```

**output:**

```
_adf
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun:

```
echo abc_dsdsds_ss_gsgsdsfsdf_ewew_wewewewewew_adf | tr _ '\n' | tail -n 1 | rev | tr '\n' _ | rev
```